# HTML5 - Push Status Desktop Notification

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I want to create a status report notification that check the db from time to time of the current status? Example: Lets say, a computer shop scenario that will show notifications 5 minutes before -- alerting the admin that the time of PC 1 is about to run out.

I tried following this tutorial, http://beakkon.com/tutorial/html5/desktop-notification, but it needs user interaction (in this case, button click) so that desktop notifications will appear. I am using PHP, jQuery, HTML as my web technology.

Also, Will the notification still appear even if I am not on the web page triggering the fetching of data?

Comment: a word of caution, html5 desktop notifications are still only available on google chrome afaik.

Comment: right, then let us assume that the user has already given the permission that notification will be allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to zvona for guiding the way. The trick will be to put the notification in a page that will be accessible by other pages in that way, notification will be accessible anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop notifications require user interaction first time, in order to allow them.

But basically you create a setInterval which makes the DB query / XHR and then triggers createNotification if certain conditions are met.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But can this still be done even if the user switch pages?

Comment: Are you building an application or a website? If you're with the application, I'd suggest it being a single-page app, rather than fighting with all the problems that come along during page refresh.

If it's already a website, then you could perhaps use a separately launched window that does nothing but communicates with the server db whether any conditions occur?